# how to get geolocation of current device with flutter?

Tags: flutter, geolocation, gps

I want to get geolocation of my device with flutter but I do not know where the problem is, I'm doing exactly like the readme file for the Flutter Geolocator Plugin and When I run it takes a long time, but it does not work and hasn't shown me error
this is my code

```
getLocation() async {
Position position = await Geolocator()
    .getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);

var geolocator = Geolocator();
var locationOptions =
    LocationOptions(accuracy: LocationAccuracy.high, distanceFilter: 10);

StreamSubscription<Position> positionStream = geolocator
    .getPositionStream(locationOptions)
    .listen((Position position) {
  print(position == null
      ? 'Unknown'
      : position.latitude.toString() +
          ', ' +
          position.longitude.toString());
});
```

}

this is the plugin
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  geolocator: '^2.0.2'

Comment: Where is getLocation being called? The initState of a stateful widget? Stateless widget build method? More information of what's going on would help.

Comment: It looks like you're combining a couple of methods. Have you tried just, Position position = await Geolocator().getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
 and then printing the position results once the future completes?